# Facebook SDK project with Errors

Tags: android, facebook

After following these steps: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/mobile/android/build/

I find that everything goes well, but when I create the new Facebook SDK project (Step 3), which I add from here: https://github.com/facebook/facebook-android-sdk

The project is full of errors in Eclipse when I open it. For example, here is one of many:

> Multiple markers at this line
>       - Line breakpoint:Facebook [line: 621] - logout(Context)
>       - The method clearCookies(Context) from the type Util refers to the missing type

I added this when creating the project: facebook-facebook-android-sdk-1f0b0ea\facebook

That's what the instructions say ... add that for the sdk. The errors are in Facebook.java, FbDialog.java, and Util.java. Is this normal? What do other people do when they have the same issue?

Also, when I added the reference to the Facebook SDK to my Android app project, the root folder in Eclipse has a red exclamation mark on it. What does that mean?

Comment: it means android.jar or facebook library is needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eclipse > Right-click project > Properties > Java Compiler > Compiler compliance level > 1.6